# Can't execute npm install

Tags: npm

When I am executing npm install this error shows. Any advice about this?

```
PS C:\Users\alex\Downloads\team> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR! @angular/compiler@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.0.3" from @angular/compiler-cli@13.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR! dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ for a full report.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\
```

Here is Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.13",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap4-toggle": "^3.6.1",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Delete the `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder and then do `npm install`

Comment: Did it but still having the same error

Comment: It might be helpful if you also post the full contents of your **package.json**

Comment: Hi, I have added the package.json to OP

Comment: seems like there's a conflict with packages like `"@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",` and `"@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",` , you should probably decide if you want the angular stuff to all be 13.1 or 13.0

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'BuiltinMethod'

Answer (score 2):

`ERESOLVE` issues with `npm@7` and `npm@8` are common because they are more strict about peer dependencies than `npm@6`. Often, the easiest resolution is to pass the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag to `npm` (e.g., `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`) or else use `npm@6`.

The "correct" solution is to figure out which of your dependencies need to be updated in `package.json` to avoid the peer dependency conflict, but that is sometimes not possible with dependencies that are unmaintained. In that case, the solution is to find or create something else to get rid of the unmaintained dependency.

However, 9 times out of 10, someone just wants to get the stuff installed and hope it works, in which case `--legacy-peer-deps` will do that. Just make sure you have good test coverage because you're using a different peer dependency version than that specified by a package so something somewhere might not work.

To see if the problem will affect your production app, do `npm install --production`. If it doesn't give you an `ERESOLVE` error, then the problem is in your dev dependencies only, which is less of a concern typically.